# Arithmetic operation in PHP String with colon ( : ) punctuation

Tags: php, time

I'm trying to solve the problem comparing two-time string and it's working fine. Here's code.

Somehow I'm not getting why it's working. How String with colon ( : )  punctuation is correctly comparing?

```php
$start = "10:00";
$end = "22:00";

if($start > $end) {
    echo "Start time is more than End time.";
} else {
    echo "End time is less than Start time.";
}
```

Now everything is working fine and output is:

> End time is less than Start time.

Sorry if I'm missing something kindly provide details into this.

Thank you.

Comment: Use the [DateTime](http://php.net/DateTime) API. A string doesn't have a concept of time formats, so when it works, it's by coincidence generally.

Comment: Not sure if *End time is less than Start time.* is correct when start is 10:00 and end is 22:00.  BUT it is just comparing strings - doesn't care if it's a `:` or any other character.

Comment: It has nothing to do with ( : )... it's basically comparing strings alphabetically... You can change the variables to "a" and "b" and vice versa to check. If you want to compare times you need to use DateTime API

Answer (score 0):

it is just comparing strings like below

```
if("overflow"=="stock"){
   echo "right";
}else{
   echo "wrong";
}
```

if you want to compare the actual values in the variable better to convert them to numbers

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert string into timestamp object. So please use following code:

```
$start = strtotime("10:00:00");
$end = strtotime("22:00:00");

if($start > $end) {
    echo "Start time is more than End time.";
} else {
    echo "End time is less than Start time.";
}
```